# Custom implementation of GRU not performing

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I created a custom implementation of a GRU in TensorFlow to experiment with.  When training, it performs nothing like the native TensorFlow GRUcell.  I've been trying to figure out why, and simply can't.  Any input will be appreciated.

**Native implementation:**

```
encoder = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(feature_no,activation = tf.nn.tanh)
encoding = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(encoder,inputs,dtype=tf.float32)[1]
```

**My implementation:**

```
class GRU:
    def __init__(self, hid_dim, vec_dim,
                 name = None):
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim                  #Dimension of the hidden layer
        self.vec_dim = vec_dim                  #Dimension of the input layer
        ## Declare the variables
        ## Update gate
        self.W_ux = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.W_ux",
                                    shape = [vec_dim, hid_dim],
                                    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.W_uh = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.W_uh",
                                    shape = [hid_dim, hid_dim],
                                    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.b_u = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.g_u",
                                   shape = [hid_dim],
                                   initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        ## Forget gate
        self.W_rx = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRUt.W_rx",
                                    shape = [vec_dim, hid_dim],
                                    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.W_rh = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.W_rh",
                                    shape = [hid_dim, hid_dim],
                                    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.b_r = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.b_r",
                                   shape = [hid_dim],
                                   initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        ## Update function
        self.W_hx = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.W_hx",
                                    shape = [vec_dim, hid_dim],
                                    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.W_hh = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.W_hh",
                                    shape = [hid_dim, hid_dim],
                                    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        self.b_h = tf.get_variable(name = name + ".GRU.b_h",
                                   shape = [hid_dim],
                                   initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())

    def update_state(self, x, h):
        u = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, self.W_ux) + tf.matmul(h, self.W_uh) +
                       self.b_u)

        ## 'Forget' gate
        r = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, self.W_rx) + tf.matmul(h, self.W_rh) + self.b_r)

        ## Hidden state
        hp = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x, self.W_hx) + r*tf.matmul(h, self.W_hh)
                        + self.b_h)
        return (1 - u) * hp + u * h

    def get_states(self, x):
        init = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.zeros_like(x[:,0,0]),[self.hid_dim]),
                                            shape = [-1,self.hid_dim])
        x_t = tf.transpose(x,perm=[1,0,2])
        self.h_set = tf.transpose(tf.scan(lambda h, x: self.update_state(x, h),
                                          x_t, init), perm = [1,0,2])
        self.h = self.h_set[:,-1]

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.get_states(x)
        return self.h

encoder = GRU(feature_no,vec_dim,name='encoder')
encoding = encoder(sent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  I know RNNs are notoriously sensitive to initialization, and yet I used `tf.random_normal_initializer()` instead of `tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()`. I made the swap, and now they perform identically.